# FCKeditor for ASP.NET: file upload size limit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, size, fckeditor

I'm working on an asp.net website written in vb. I embedded fdkeditor in my page, and it works fine. As it includes image-upload feature, which works fine as well, I need to limit the size of the file before it's been uploaded.

I wonder I couldn't find anyting satisfactory on web, it seems fckeditor's developers haven't ever thought about that.

Has anyone workarounded it?

Thanks

Comment: What is FCKEditor using for the file upload? If it's a normal HTML file input, you're out of luck, since you can't access the file size on the client side. You'll need to hack together something with Flash in order to access local file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I've not dealt with this issue (FCKEditor), but does this help? http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=9930

As Matti points out above, if it uses the default HTML file input then you're out of luck because there's no way to check file size on the client-side before uploading (at which point, if it's too big, only then does it throw an exception).